# Failing to solve a simple PDE with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following PDE.
Actually this is a major simplification of the original with all x,z dependent coefficients being fixed.
For some reason Mathematica (10.0) cannot solve even this equation.

```
xmax = 3.;
zmin = 100.;
zmax = 121.;
eqlist = {-170.2 (0.005 D[Ne[t, x, z], z] - D[Ne[t, x, z], {z, 2}]) - 
     3436. (0.005 D[Ne[t, x, z], x] - D[Ne[t, x, z], {x, 2}]) + 
     D[Ne[t, x, z], t] == 0.,
Ne[t, x, 100.] == 1.,
Ne[t, x, 121.] == 1.,
Ne[t, -3., z] == 1.,
Ne[t, 3., z] == 1.,
Ne[0, x, z] == 1. + 10. E^(-99.9 x^2 - 1. (-110. + z)^2)};
```

The call for NDSolve is:

```
sol2=NDSolve[eqlist,{Ne},{t,0, tmax},{x,-xmax,xmax},{z,zmin,zmax}];
```

Which results in:

```
NDSolve::mxsst: Using maximum number of grid points 100 allowed by the MaxPoints or MinStepSize options for independent variable x. >>
NDSolve::mxsst: Using maximum number of grid points 100 allowed by the MaxPoints or MinStepSize options for independent variable x. >>
NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 6.627302565895071`*^-29. >>
NDSolve::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 602.8342054919686` at t = 6.627302565895071`*^-29 in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 101 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options. >>
```

In addition I've also tried Methods of Lines with the same results.

```
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 1010}
```

Edit: Added my code as Input Text.

Can someone please help me?

Many thanks in advance,
Yevgeny

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: If you post the `InputForm` of your code, others will be able to copy and paste it into their *Mathematica*.  This will make it easier for others to try to help you.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, Thanks - I've read the Tour and will use the other suggestions.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I've pasted the `Input Text` as you suggested.

Comment: @yep, What's `tmax`?

Comment: Are sure the signs of the equation are correct?

Comment: I have replaced the conditions with `DirichletCondition` and it solves the equation.

Comment: @user21, tmax=1.
I'm pretty sure about the signs.

Comment: @m0nhawk Are these your `DirichletConditions`? Because I'm still resulting in a very long and unsuccessful computation.
`DirichletCondition[Ne[t, x, z] == 1., z == zmin],`

`DirichletCondition[Ne[t, x, z] == 1., z == zmax],`

`DirichletCondition[Ne[t, x, z] == 1., x == -xmax],`

`DirichletCondition[Ne[t, x, z] == 1., x == xmax],`

`DirichletCondition[Ne[t, x, z] == 1. + 10. E^(-99.9 x^2 - 1. (-110. + z)^2), t == 0] `

Comment: @yep This works for me: [gist](https://gist.github.com/m0nhawk/4dc01861f609f71201d3).

Comment: @m0nhawk Although a bit different, but `DirichletCondition` solved the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @yep And does the solution looks like the intended?

Comment: @m0nhawk Yes, thanks. Do you wish to post an answer to receive points?